# best way to remove '-' in oracle SP

Tags: oracle

I have an Oracle stored procedure, that has as one of its parameters a Social Security Number (SSN) in the hyphenated format xxx-xx-xxxx.  What is the best way to remove the hyphens, so that I transform the SSN to a xxxxxxxxx format?

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Answer (score 8):

```
REPLACE('xxx-xx-xxxx', '-', '')
```

Or as @jitter mentions, the third argument defaults to `''`, so:

```
REPLACE('xxx-xx-xxxx', '-')
```

Comment: Or shorter REPLACE(yourstringhere, '-')

Comment: thanks! and what if I have xxxxxxxxx and I want to turn it into xxx-xx-xxxx?

Comment: I am trying to use this in a procedure but get the following error:  'REPLACE' is not a procedure or is undefined

Comment: REPLACE is a function eg 
new_val := REPLACE(old_val,'-');

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question, if you already have the xxx-xx-xxxx version, don't overwrite it and you'll have both.

If you're expecting xxxxxxxxx and you want xxx-xx-xxxx, piece it together using:

```
SUBSTR('xxxxxxxxx', 0, 3) || '-' || SUBSTR('xxxxxxxxx', 3, 2) || '-' || SUBSTR('xxxxxxxxx', 5, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

mystring := v_mySSN;
select substr(mystring, 0, 3)||'-'||substr(mystring, 3, 2)||'-'||substr(mystring, 5, 4)
into varialble
from some_table;

This would work inside a procedure to select your value in a variable correctly.